# Are there page checkers in WATIN which execute on each page load?

Tags: watin, watir

I am writing automation scripts using WATIR and WATIN. Watir has something called page checkers, which are code snippets that run on each page load. Is there something similar in WATIN ? I want a piece of code to run on each page load. Generally this is used to check for page errors or page loading images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really that easy to tell when page loads. I quickly googled about that page checkers in Watir, that you mentioned and found [an article about page checkers in Watir](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/08/19/how-to-check-for-errors-on-every-page-using-watir/). See first comment bellow the article. AFAIK it's really similar in WatiN.

Unfortunately, I don't see any similar functionality in WatiN (no event is fired after internal call to `WaitForComplete`. The easiest thing you could do is to subclass eg. `IE` class:

```
class MyIE : IE
{
    public MyIE(string url) : base(url) { } //TODO: add constructors

    public override void WaitForComplete(int waitForCompleteTimeOut)
    {
        base.WaitForComplete(waitForCompleteTimeOut);
        Console.WriteLine("Page has been loaded");
    }
}
```

However, the situation will be similar to described in mentioned comment (*runs a lot more regularly than just page load*).

I think that better approach would be using `Page` class from WatiN library. It is well documented. Example for watin.org webpage:

```
var ie = new MyIE("http://watin.org/");

var homePage = ie.Page<HomePage>();
Console.WriteLine(homePage.FirstFeature);
homePage.DocumentationLink.Click();

var documentationPage = ie.Page<DocumentationPage>();
Console.WriteLine(documentationPage.FAQLink.Url);
```

To run that code you need following classes:

```
abstract class WatiNBasePage : Page
{
    [FindBy(Id = "header")]
    public Div HeaderDiv { get; set; }

    public Link HomeLink { get { return HeaderDiv.Link(Find.ByText("Home")); } }

    public Link DocumentationLink { get { return HeaderDiv.Link(Find.ByText("Documentation")); } }

    protected override void InitializeContents()
    {
        base.InitializeContents();
        VerifyDocumentProperties(UnverifiedDocument, errorMessage => { throw new Exception(errorMessage); }); //TODO: modify if needed
    }

    protected override void VerifyDocumentProperties(Document document, Page.ErrorReporter errorReporter)
    {
        base.VerifyDocumentProperties(document, errorReporter);
        if (!HomeLink.Exists)
            errorReporter("HomeLink not exists");
        //TODO: more checks here
    }
}

class HomePage : WatiNBasePage
{
    [FindBy(Id = "features")]
    public Table FeatureTable { get; set; }

    public string FirstFeature { get { return FeatureTable.Span(Find.First()).Text; } }
}

class DocumentationPage : WatiNBasePage
{
    [FindBy(Text = "Frequently Asked Questions")]
    public Link FAQLink { get; set; }
}
```

Basically you need to implement `VerifyDocumentProperties`. Above code will check if `HomeLink` exists, but maybe you would like to check if `DocumentationLink` exists etc. The second thing is to modify call to `VerifyDocumentProperties`. Now, if verification fails, `Exception` will be thrown after calling `ie.Page<T>()` (where T is a subclass of WatinBaseClass).

In my opinion, even if you don't need to use "page checkers", using `Page` class is still really useful and clarifies the code, so I really recommend using it. I regret that I haven't discovered it when I was starting work with WatiN.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try out this approach. My specific use case is that the product I am testing shows loading graphics while page data is being loaded synchronously or asynchronously (AJAX) and I have to wait till it disappears so that all the required page components are visible.

Comment: The `Page` class is very useful for these types of assertions. It is also helpful for accessing elements of a page through objects. See the following for more details: http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-page-class.html